# How to prevent a user from entering wrong time format(Client-side)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, data-annotations, timespan

My model includes two properties that hold the time. I want to user enter the times in view and prevent it from wrong values for example(07:66)
if you know a way in JQuery mask its ok.

```
public class WeeklyVW
{
   [StringLength(5)]
 //or time span
    public string Ws_startTime { get; set; }
   [StringLength(5)]
    public string Ws_EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

in view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Starthour, new { data_mask = "00:00", @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Both server side and client side validation is required. You can use Regex for server side validation.

Comment: @ManpritSinghSahota I want to prevent user in view

Comment: Have you tried setting the property types as `TimeSpan` ?

Comment: To add to @ManpritSinghSahota, you /should/ validate on the client side (browser), you MUST validate on the server side, otherwise you will find that miscreants will crash your site by sending invalid times.

Comment: @Neil  Yes, just show time format in text box.i want to prevent user or show him a message that input is wrong.

Comment: @Sherviniv Is this what you are looking for? https://dotnetfiddle.net/6GpRBu

Comment: @RahulSharma Yes thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your functonality by decorating your model attribute with `[DataType(DataType.Time)]` and then formatting the time input field according to your need. The second thing that you require is to use the `EditorFor` tag instead of `TextBoxFor` in order for this to work. Your code would look like:

Model:

```
public class WeeklyVW
{
  [StringLength(5)]
  //or time span
  public string Ws_startTime { get; set; }
  [StringLength(5)]
  public string Ws_EndTime { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [DataType(DataType.Time)]
  [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH}")]
  public string Starthour {get;set;}
}
```

Conntroller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new WeeklyVW());
}
```

View:

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.WeeklyVW
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- CSS Includes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <style type="text/css">

            .field-validation-error {
                color: #ff0000;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1>Time Input Example</h1>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Starthour, new { data_mask = "00:00", @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Starthour)    
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- JS includes -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

A working example of the application can be found at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6GpRBu
Or

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndHour, new { @class = "form-control ", @type = "time" })
```

if the length equals 5 textbox cant get anymore values
Model

```
  [StringLength(5)]
  public string EndHour{ get; set;}
```